# Looking for simple photo organizing software for Linux

Tags: software-rec, images, file-manager

I am looking for a simple Linux software to organize photos. What exactly I want to do with this application is the following: I want to view all images in a given folder and just tag/star/mark some of them with by simple key pressing or a simple mouse click. No menu, not complicated 10-mouse click journey, just ONE key pressing/mouse click and on to the next image. 
After I have selected a couple of images that way, I want them moved to another directory.

Is there such a simple application?

I just want to simply organize my photos in different folders, as simple as that. No tagging which is software-dependent, as I want to view those images on differrent OS, like Linux, Windows, on TV, ... Therefore, no special tagging format, just simple reorganizing photos on the touch of a simple keystroke...

Answer (score 1):

The simplest photo viewer I've found that shows folders is [geeqie](http://geeqie.sourceforge.net/).

[image]

Comment: Can I simply tag/mark the photo I am looking at?

Comment: @Alex - I thought you said you didn't want/need any tagging functionality?